# File get contents php from another url

Tags: php, file-get-contents

In short I'm using this code to get contents from another url

```
file_get_contents("http://www . xyz . net/data.php");
```

The problem I'm facing is that in the above url the data is showing up but after a huge space.
I want to say is that the above url contains a big space then the data so the process of `file_get_contents` is taking so much time, any suggestions to improve it ??

maybe you can get understand by this screenshot link:

[Screenshot link](http://oi39.tinypic.com/zk30bc.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried using trim() on your result? The resource is here: http://www.php.net/trim

Comment: In php you can trim whitespace

Comment: can you tell me in brief how by showing up any example related to my question?

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
$YOUR_DATA_STRING = file_get_contents("http://www.xyz.net/data.php");    
$string = trim($YOUR_DATA_STRING);   //trim space,newline from start and end of data
$string = str_replace(array("\r", "\n", "\t"), '', $string)  //remove newline, tab from whole data string
```

Comment: I am not saying that it will reduce processing time. It will remove extra spaces around received data.

Comment: then you have to check your data.php page, whether its working properly or not.